# Text to columns for a large field

Tags: r, tidyr

So I have a Column below "Names" which is pipe delimited, 1 cell of this column appears as follows:

Tom Miner | John Smith | Mary Lane | Tom Bell | Steve Hall | Martin Long | John Small | Mark Tall | Ann Ball | Alan Call | David Fall | Clint Mall |

it is a 10,000 field dataframe and I want to create 4 New columns for "Names" with the first 4 names from the field:

```
Lead Actor    Lead Supporting Actor   Supporting Actor 1    Supporting Actor 2 
Tom Miner     John Smith              Mary Lane             Tom Bell
```

there could be as many as 40 names in the column or as few as 10
but I only want to split the field out to the 4 columns above.

I tried reshape and tidyr but cant get this to work, any help appreciated.

The column is "Names":

Cell 1 Brad Pitt | Tommy Lee Jones | Ruth Negga | John Ortiz | Liv Tyler | Donald Sutherland | Greg Bryk | Loren Dean | Kimberly Elise | John Finn | LisaGay Hamilton | Donnie Keshawarz | Bobby Nish | Sean Blakemore | Freda Foh Shen | Kayla Adams | Ravi Kapoor | Elisa Perry | Daniel Sauli | Kimmy Shields | Kunal Dudheker | Alyson Reed | Sasha CompÃ¨re | Justin Dray | Alexandria Rousset | Natasha Lyonne | Zoro Saro Manuel Daghlian | Jacob Sandler | Elizabeth Willaman

Cell 2  Vin Diesel | Eiza GonzÃ¡lez | Sam Heughan | Toby Kebbell | Talulah Riley | Lamorne Morris | Guy Pearce | JÃ³hannes Haukur JÃ³hannesson | Alex Hernandez | Siddharth Dhananjay | Tamer Burjaq | Clyde Berning | David Dukas | Tyrel Meyer | Alex Anlos | Maarten RÃ¶mer | Patrick Kerton | Ryan Kruger
Will Smith | Martin Lawrence | Paola NuÃ±ez | Vanessa Hudgens | Alexander Ludwig | Charles Melton | Kate del Castillo | Nicky Jam | Joe Pantoliano | Theresa Randle | Jacob Scipio | Massi Furlan | Michael Bay | DJ Khaled | Derrick Gilbert | Jay Dubb | Emily Towles | Scott Rapp | Happy Anderson | Melissa Kennemore | Jennifer Badger | Bianca Bethune | Dennis Greene | Jenin Gonzalez

Cell 3: Paul Rudd | Michael Douglas | Evangeline Lilly | Corey Stoll | Bobby Cannavale | Anthony Mackie | Judy Greer | Abby Ryder Fortson | Michael PeÃ±a | David Dastmalchian | T.I. | Wood Harris | Hayley Atwell | John Slattery | Martin Donovan | Garrett Morris | Gregg Turkington | Rod Hallett | Joe Chrest | Joe Bucaro III | Jean Louisa Kelly | Dax Griffin | Hayley Lovitt | Anna Akana | Stan Lee | Chris Evans | Sebastian Stan | Tom Kenny | Norma Alvarez | Darcie Isabella Cottrell | Teddy Williams | Carol Anne Watts | Chuck David Willis | Diana Chiritescu | Neko Parham | Onira Tares | Kylen Davis | Zamani Wilder | Jim R. Coleman | Desmond Phillips | Aaron Saxton | Michael A. Cook | Ricki Lander | Rus Blackwell | Johnny Pemberton | Nicholas Barrera | Carlos Aviles | Lyndsi LaRose | Robert Crayton | Ajani Perkins | Jessejames Locorriere | Zack Duhame | Kevin Lacz | Michael Trisler | Daniel Stevens | Alex Chansky | Clay Donahue Fontenot | Michael Jamorski | Casey Pieretti | Antal Kalik | Adam Hart | Reuben Langdon | Todd Schneider | Kevin Buttimer | Danny Vasquez | Rick Avery | Erik Betts

The outcome I want to achieve is
Person 1    Person 2          Person 3     Person 4
Brad Pitt   Tommy Lee Jones   Ruth Negga   John Ortiz

so 5 new columns in my dataframe - the rest of the names in the cell not required

Comment: With “field” do you mean column, or cell? Is it a column with multiple cells, each having many pipe-separated values, or one single vector that is 10.000 values long? It’s always most useful to give a reproducible example, preferably actual R code that others can run to get the data (or a dummy dataset with the qualities of your data) you’re working with

Comment: can you give us a more complete sample of your data? use the `dput()` command and include it in your question

Comment: Also please add few more lines of your expected output. As from other comments, you must have realized that your question is not clear and difficult to understand.  Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I added 3 cells above - essentially each cell could have up to 40 Actors.

Comment: I want to each out the first 4/5 names into new columns, with their own headings

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data has a column with 10,000 cells & each of the cells have values similar to the example that you provided, you can use `separate` from `tidyr` package.

```
# sample data 
df <- data.frame(Names = "Tom Miner | John Smith | Mary Lane | Tom Bell | Steve Hall | Martin Long | John Small", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(tidyr)
df %>% separate(Names, c("Lead Actor", "Lead Supporting Actor", "Supporting Actor 1", "Supporting Actor 2"), sep = " \\| ", extra = "drop")
```

Here, the code is separating `Names` (the column with all the names) by the separator " | " (with escape ('\') for the string '|'), and we are keeping the first four and dropping the rest.

Fore more info on `separate` : https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html